# How to display the execution result in remote linux screen(command input via ssh)?

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal, x11, remote-access

everyone :

I need ssh to connect remote linux ,I already know how to run and display a GUI program in remote linux .It can be done by :

```
ssh username@ip
export DISPLAY=:0.0
firefox &
```

however ,my target linux hasn't X Window System , I need display the execution result in remote linux's screen ,for example :

my pc is A , remote pc is B

A use ssh access B , after connected to B ,I type ls in A then press enter

the execution result should display in B's screen (tty or whatever , I don't know what it should be called)

any idea? thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basic idea:

```
a$ ssh user@b
b$ run-program >/dev/console
```

(I use `a$` and `b$` to indicate the shell prompts on A and B respectively.)

Problem with this:

```
b$ ls -l /dev/console
crw------- 1 root root 5, 1 Mar 19 09:10 /dev/console
```

Only root can write to `/dev/console`.

Possible workaround:

```
$b run-program | sudo tee /dev/console >/dev/null
```

(Redirecting to `/dev/null` here prevents the output from showing up on your screen as well.)

This does depend on `user@b` being allowed to run `sudo tee /dev/console`.

If you are sysadmin for B and `user@b` is not allowed to run `sudo tee /dev/console`, read [`man 5 sudoers`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/sudoers) and [`man 8 visudo`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/visudo) to find out how to give `user@b` this permission.

If you are *not* sysadmin for B and `user@b` is not allowed to run `sudo tee /dev/console`, you will have to ask B's sysadmin to set this up for you.